# How to sign setup with .crt file?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, code-signing

I've got a Comodo certificate to sign my application files with the appropriate publisher (that'll be me). 
But how do I sign my installation to prevent those triple "are you sure?" UAC dialogs?

Am using the Visual Studio (2008) setup project, no third party tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can disable UAC dialogs. For installer signing, I think `signtool` in the Windows SDK will do what you need.